# I want to show dropdown menu only from his own button inside my own Component that has been looped with array map method in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

### Hello Everyone

I have a `React Native` project which also using a framework [UI Kitten](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/) for my UI/UX and [Realm](https://realm.io/) for my Database

#### First

I have **Data** retrieved coming from my database, **look like this**

```
[
  {
    name: "Eric",
    age: 21,
    city: "Jakarta"
  },

  {
    name: "Alex",
    age: 18,
    city: "Surabaya"
  }
]
```

#### Second

**[UI Kitten](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/)** has a dropdown Component it's called **[Overflow Menu](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/overflow-menu/overview#overflowmenu)**. **To show that Data** in the Screen I made my own Component and inside the Component I am adding a dropdown or `OverflowMenu` and last thing I loop my Component using Array `.map()` method to displaying every data, soo the User can do a thing with every **Data** that has been shown.

**Example code look like this**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Text, OverflowMenu, MenuItem, Button } from '@ui-kitten/components';

const ShowPersonData = (props) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Name: {props.personName}</Text>
      <Text>Age: {props.personAge}</Text>
      <Text>City: {props.personCity}</Text>

      <OverflowMenu
        { // This is trigger button for show a dropdown menu }
        anchor={() => (<Button onPress={props.onPressMenu}>ShowDropdown</Button>)}
        visible={props.visibleDropdown} { // Show or Hide }
        onBackdropPress={props.onPressOutsideMenu}> { // When press outside dropdown menu }
          <MenuItem title='Edit'/>
          <MenuItem title='Delete'/>
          <MenuItem title='Details'/>
      </OverflowMenu>
    </View>
  );
};

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      visibleDropdown: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    const PersonData = [
      {
        name: "Eric",
        age: 21,
        city: "Jakarta"
      },

      {
        name: "Alex",
        age: 18,
        city: "Surabaya"
      }
    ];

    return(
      <View>
        {
          PersonData.map((person, index) => {
            <ShowPersonData
              key={index}
              personName={person.name}
              personAge={person.age}
              personCity={person.city}
              onPressMenu={() => this.setState({ visibleDropdown: true })} { // I have no idea }
              visibleDropdown={this.state.visibleDropdown} { // I have no idea }
              onPressOutsideMenu={() => this.setState({ visibleDropdown: false })}
              />
          })
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

#### The Problem

I have no idea **How to make the dropdown menu is shown if only his own button is pressed**, in the example above it just shows all the dropdown menus in each Component that I have looped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem of your code** is you're looping a `function` that returning a JSX Element and that a totally wrong **If** you're trying to show a dropdown menu from his own button.

**Simple Explained**

If you want to show a dropdown menu from his own button you have to make his own `state` too, in your code, I see a core problem where you're using a `MyComponent state` for showing that dropdown menu and automatically if you press one button in you're component that has been looped with `.map()` method all entire dropdown menu will show, because you only use one `state`

**How to fix?**

Create a new file called **PersonDataShowcase.jsx** the code look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Text, OverflowMenu, MenuItem, Button } from '@ui-kitten/components';

export default class PersonDataShowcase extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      visibleDropdown: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { personName, personAge, personCity } = this.props

    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Name: {personName}</Text>
        <Text>Age: {personAge}</Text>
        <Text>City: {personCity}</Text>

        <OverflowMenu
          anchor={() => (<Button onPress={() => this.setState({ visibleDropdown: true })}>ShowDropdown</Button>)}
          visible={this.state.visibleDropdown}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ visibleDropdown: false })}>
            <MenuItem title='Edit'/>
            <MenuItem title='Delete'/>
            <MenuItem title='Details'/>
        </OverflowMenu>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

And `import` that file in your **Home.jsx** or anywhere you want to show that data, and just **Code** like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import PersonDataShowcase from './path/to/PersonDataShowcase.jsx';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const PERSON_DATA = [
      {
        name: "Eric",
        age: 21,
        city: "Jakarta"
      },

      {
        name: "Alex",
        age: 18,
        city: "Surabaya"
      }
    ];

    return(
      <View>
        {
          PERSON_DATA.map((person, index) => {
            <PersonDataShowcase
              personName={person.name}
              personAge={person.age}
              personCity={person.city}
            />
          })
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Now your problem should be solved, and the dropdown menu will be shown only from his own button